# Determine cell tower operator

Tags: cellphone

Pre: I'd understand if this isn't strictly related to electronics but I believe that this is something that would interest electronics enthusiasts.

I have a cell tower 2 buildings down from mine. I wish to know it's operator (so that I can switch) . I have a dual SIM phone. Short of buying SIM of every carrier and putting it in slot 1 and opening OpenSignal, what are my options to find out who operates the cell tower? Ive searched on opencellid.com but they don't list the tower at all.

PS: sorry for the bad tag but on phone I don't get the suggestion list

Comment: It can very well serve several operators. Anyway, go there and look for labels. Or catch some maintenance worker and ask.

Comment: websearch SUCCESS depends on guessing the BEST keywords. I  used **Mobile tower map {toronto}**  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jgQ6.jpg